# SQL Query Merge record

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Basically I want to create this result in query :

[image]

from above table into below table (new record)

Already try using CTE but I have no clue to solve this problem, just stuck how to get started.

thank you.

Comment: What have you tried? And how should anyone guess how this data is aggregated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
(
    Field1 DATETIME,
    Field2 VARCHAR(20),
    Field3 VARCHAR(20),
    Field4 VARCHAR(20),
    Field5 VARCHAR(20),
    Field6 INT,
    Field7 INT,
    Field8 VARCHAR(20),
    Field9 INT
)

INSERT INTO @T
VALUES('12/17/2017 10:39:00','A','AA','HB','KT',123,1234,'Over',1000),
('12/17/2017 10:42:00','B','BB','2506','8239',456,789,'Over',850),
('12/17/2017 10:47:00','A','AA','HB','KT',123,1234,'Over',850),
('12/17/2017 10:50:00','B','BB','2506','8239',456,789,'Over',700)

;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
       RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY MAX(Field2) ORDER BY CAST(Field1 AS DATE)),
       Field1D = CAST(Field1 AS DATE),
       Field1Tmin = MIN(CAST(Field1 AS TIME)) OVER(PARTITION BY MAX(Field2)),
       Field1Tmax = MAX(CAST(Field1 AS TIME)) OVER(PARTITION BY MAX(Field2)),
       Field2 = MAX(Field2),
       Field3 = MAX(Field3),
       Field4 = MAX(Field4),
       Field5 = MAX(Field5),
       Field6 = MAX(Field6),
       Field7 = MAX(Field7),
       Field8 = MAX(Field8),
       Field9 = SUM(Field9)
       FROM @T
          GROUP BY CAST(Field1 AS DATE),CAST(Field1 AS TIME)
)
SELECT 
    DISTINCT
    Field1 = CAST(Field1Tmin AS VARCHAR(20))+'-'+CAST(Field1Tmax AS VARCHAR(20)),
    Field2,
    Field3,
    Field4,
    Field5,
    Field6,
    Field7,
    Field8,
    Field9 = SUM(Field9) OVER(PARTITION BY CAST(Field1Tmin AS VARCHAR(20))+'-'+CAST(Field1Tmax AS VARCHAR(20)))/COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY CAST(Field1Tmin AS VARCHAR(20))+'-'+CAST(Field1Tmax AS VARCHAR(20)))
    FROM CTE
```

Result

[image]

I know It is not a straight way, But This might work in your case.

Comment: i dont know if there is any other way except this

Comment: There are a lot and don't require converting time to strings or partitioning over the strings. A query has to perform well to be useful.

Comment: thank you for your valuable respon, it just perfect but there is one thing that I need to ask, in field1 I need to check based on the hour, so when I add new data with field1 _12/17/2017 11:50:00_ then the result split into 3 record wih 10:00-11:00 (2 records) and 11:00-12:00 (1 record)